# R plot data.frame to get more effective overview of data

Tags: r, plot, visualization

At work when I want to understand a dataset (I work with portfolio data in life insurance), I would normally use pivot tables in Excel to look at e.g. the development of variables over time or dependencies between variables.
I remembered from university the nice R-function where you can plot every column of a dataframe against every other column like in:

[image]

For the dependency between issue.age and duration this plot is actually interesting because you can clearly see that high issue ages come with shorter policy durations (because there is a maximum age for each policy). However the plots involving the issue year `iss.year` are much less "visual". In fact you cant see anything from them. I would like to see with once glance if the distribution of issue ages has changed over the different issue.years, something like

[image]

where you could see immediately that the average age of newly issue policies has been increasing from 2014 to 2016.

I don't want to write code that needs to be customized for every dataset that I put in because then I can also do it faster manually in Excel.

So my question is, is there an easy way to plot each column of a matrix against every other column with more flexible chart types than with the standard `plot(data.frame)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ggpairs()` function from the [`GGally` library](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally). It has a lot of capability for visualizing columns of all different types, and provides a lot of control over what to visualize.

For example, here is a snippet from the vignette linked to above:

```
data(tips, package = "reshape")
ggpairs(tips)
```

[image: ggpair example visualization]

Comment: That is absolutely incredible, thank you so much. I knew there must be something like this!